# Use cx_Oracle insert data and multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cx-oracle

I have 10 million data need to do some data wrangling 
and after that this dataframe will be inserted into Oracle.
It is so big that I try to split them for 10 times, so that I can handle 1 million for a time.Here is my code:

```
for i in range(10):
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000000)     
    # change rows into dataframe
    df_nps = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])
    # data_preprocessing
    df_nps = data_preprocessing(df_nps)
    # insert the clean data into Oracle
    cursor2 = conn.cursor()
    cursor2.executemany('''insert into table_A(sdate,first_name) values(:1,:2)''', df_nps)
    conn.commit()
```

Now,I want to use Python multiprocessing so that maybe it can work faster for a time.However,I was curious that if I use multiprocessing in the loop above, coming to `cursor2.executemany`, will table_A be locked?

Comment: Indeed, sql does task in multi-thread, it is generally meaningless for you to do multiprocessing on your own. But for your question, it should be no.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a session pool and create multiple threads, and in each thread you acquire a connection from the pool which inserts a number of rows into the table that should work for you. You may wish to do it in smaller batches in order to tune the amount of time spent in Python (which will be single threaded due to the GIL) and the amount spent waiting for the database to complete the insert.